# Passing Argument by Reference in PHP

Tags: php, function, reference

I started studying PHP and I have a question about passing arguments by reference in a function.

I wrote this code:

```
<?php
    $str = "ciao";
    increment($str);
    
    function increment(&$str){
        strtoupper($str);
    }
    echo $str."\n";
?>
```

The result is "ciao" instead of "CIAO".

Why if I pass a variable, like $str, by reference to a function,  the original variable dosen't come modify?. I though  String $str is immutable in php (like Java) but it's not so. To modify the original value I should write

```
$str=strtoupper($str);
```

instead of

```
strtoupper($str);
```

So, in general, why if I pass an argument by reference in a function in PHP I have to save in the same varible the modify that i do in the function's body?

I hope to be clear, thanks

Luca

Comment: [`strtoupper`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) function definition doesn't have pass by reference as of now and you can't force it manually

Comment: You are missing $str=strtoupper($str); inside function.

Answer (score 3):

`strtoupper()` returns the result of its action, so you need to put that result  back into the variable regardless of wether that variable is passed by reference or not.

```
function increment(&$str){
    $str = strtoupper($str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is not with passing an argument to reference, but how [strtoupper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) itself works.

If instead of `strtoupper` you were doing something else, such as this

```
<?php

function increment(&$num)
{
    $num++;
}

$n = 1;
increment($n);

echo $n."\n";
```

you would see that the `$n` variable outside is changed by the function.

But `strtoupper` doesn't modify the variable in place: it returns the uppercased value instead.

So that's why you need to reassign the value returned by `strtoupper` to the variable:

```
<?php
    $str = "ciao";
    increment($str);
    
    function increment(&$str){
        $str = strtoupper($str);
    }
    echo $str."\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I thought the same thing and I think it's so...but in your example $n++ in the function is the same thing as writing $n=$n+1 and this doesn't change the question..